# Flex Builder : How to use a specific firefox profile for launching?

Tags: firefox, flexbuilder

I tried doing the above by giving the following params in
Window -> Preferences -> Web Browser -> Edit -> Parameters :
`-P devpro -no-remote`

But whenever I run an application from flex builder,
it asks me to choose a profile.

I also tried:

```
-P "devpro" -no-remote
-P %devpro% -no-remote
-P "devpro"
-P %devpro%
```

None of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the full path to Firefox:

```
 "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe" -p devpro -no-remote
```

The above assumes Windows, for Mac/Linux, I *think* it would be:

```
 -a firefox -p devpro -no-remote
```